# How to publish an IntelliJ IDEA project as a Gist

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, version-control, gist

I have a very simple IntelliJ IDEA project that I would like to publish as a Gist.

GitHub will not let me create a Gist without putting some content in it, so I made a 1-line file `gistfile1.txt`.

When I then try to connect my IDEA project to the Gist repository, it rejects my attempts at pushing, apparently because of the existence of this file. I've tried Fetch, Pull, and Push repeatedly, with no success.

What is the secret to connecting a Project to a Gist?

Update: trying to use the Create Gist... command, but still getting rejected. Latest error messages:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gist.github.com/1bf9d3b0ab2ebc7745e4780f9e7769fa.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
To https://gist.github.com/1bf9d3b0ab2ebc7745e4780f9e7769fa.git
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
!   refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master [rejected] (non-fast-forward)
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
Done
17:00:16.729: [WorldSeriesOddsGist] git -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false pull --progress --no-stat -v --progress origin master
From https://gist.github.com/1bf9d3b0ab2ebc7745e4780f9e7769fa
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 = [up to date]      master     -> origin/master
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Update 2: I give up. Here is latest batch of error messages. Who knew Gist doesn't support directories. It says it is a normal Git repository, and I presumed that meant directories.

```
18:24:12.754: [WorldSeriesOddsGist] git -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false fetch origin --progress --prune
18:24:43.021: [WorldSeriesOddsGist] git -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false push --progress --porcelain origin refs/heads/master:master
Counting objects: 10, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 1.33 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 10 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), completed with 1 local object.        
remote: Gist does not support directories.        
remote: These are the directories that are causing problems:        
remote: .idea, net        
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gist.github.com/RobLewis/1bf9d3b0ab2ebc7745e4780f9e7769fa'
To https://gist.github.com/RobLewis/1bf9d3b0ab2ebc7745e4780f9e7769fa
!   refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master [remote rejected] (pre-receive hook declined)
Done
```

Comment: Are you creating an anonymous Gist? If not what is your auth type, token or password? What error message do you see exactly?

Comment: No, it's a public Gist here: https://gist.github.com/RobLewis/f84946b2bdc050dd9b3d707f916b6fb3 I don't know what auth type or token are and I don't want to disclose my GitHub password. The latest error message is "refusing to merge unrelated histories".

Comment: Your local history is not synchronized with the remote history. The easier would be to create a new Gist.

Comment: That's fine, but as I noted GitHub won't let me create a Gist without putting something in the `gistfile1.txt` file and this seems to mess things up. And how do I "unhook" my local Project from the current Gist repository?

Comment: Before pushing changes to the gist repo, you can pull first by `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories`, then what's the result for `git push` to the gist repo?

Answer (score 2):

To create a new Gist:

1. Right click the project on the left pane and select `Create Gist...`
2. Click Anonymous if you don't want to link it with your github account
3. Enter a description
4. Click Ok

Comment: Well damn, that couldn't be much easier! Thank you! If anyone would like to see it, it's here: https://gist.github.com/RobLewis/e519b033b729dedfc3fa2926cd2677ef

Comment: Oops, spoke too soon. With new Gist, still rejecting. I have added the latest error messages to the original question.